# In mod_security, POST & "multipart/form-data" is not working

Tags: apache, post, form-data, mod-security

I'd like to deny by POST & REQUEST_BODY string condition in mod_security(ModSecurity).
But It is failed in "multipart/form-data". Please help me...

**Details**

- POST & "x-www-form-urlencoded" is not problem.(denied)
- Of course, "SecRequestBodyAccess" is activated in conf.
- Example rule.

```
SecRule REQUEST_BODY "server" "id:1234,phase:2,t:none,deny"

> The above sample excludes POST conditions.
```

- Debug log ("multipart/form-data")

```
??????? Multipart: Added part header "Content-Disposition" "form-data; name=\"server\""
~~~
??????? Adding request argument (BODY): name "server", value "sample"
~~~
Starting phase REQUEST_BODY.

~~~
??????? SecRule REQUEST_BODY "@rx server" "id:1234,phase:2,t:none,deny"
??????? Rule returned 0. ---- Not found.
```

- mod_security version: version 2 series.
- I tried other many tests. But I have no idea.

Comment: I could fix with using "ARGS_POST_NAMES|ARGS_POST". However, I'd like to know how to do this with REQUEST_BODY alone if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this is a ModSecurity question and not an OWASP CRS question, I try to answer and help as CRS dev-on-duty: It is known that in ModSecurity the `REQUEST_BODY` variable

> is available only if the URLENCODED request body processor
> was used, which will occur by default when the
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type is detected.

See here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#request_body

So your solution to test for `ARGS` instead of `REQUEST_BODY` is a good solution.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I was interpreting "REQUEST_BODY" with just keyword. "application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type is detected",,, It's confusing.